# Anylogic: Dynamically change source rate using variable/slider

Tags: anylogic

[image: source]

I am trying to dynamically change the source Arrival rate using a variable "arrivalRate" linked to a slider (see image).

However, during the simulation the initial rate remains the same, even when I change the arrivalRate. I know that the arrivalRate variable is changing successfully (it is an int) - but this has no effect on the source rate during the simulation.

Anyone have an idea what the issue is - or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see the `=` sign before a field, it means it's not dynamic, it is only evaluated at the start of the model or at the element creation and will not change throughout the simulation run unless you force it. In other words, the variable `arrivalRate` is checked only once to assign the source's arrival rate and that's it.

Now if you want to change it dynamically, in the slider's `Action` field, write the following:

```
source.set_rate( arrivalRate );
```

Comment: Hi Emile - thank you for your help and suggestion! To test your suggestion I built a very simple model with only source -> sink, with one variable and one slider (just to make sure there was nothing else interfering). Unfortunately it still resulted in an unpredictable rate. Maybe "by design" a source.set_rate is not meant to be used within source?

Comment: I tested it and it worked

Comment: https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/source.html

Comment: "You can use arrival rate (and change it dynamically by calling set_rate()), "

Comment: Make sure you have your time units setup correctly.

Comment: Hi Emil. Found the source of the problem. I set the Arrival rate for source to "per hour". When I use the set_rate function, it sets a "per second" value which obviously creates an output that is much to high...at least now I know where to attack the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, as expected in my previous comment, you had inconsistent time units. But the root problem you had was that the arrival rate is not dynamic, you need to change it by using the `set_rate` function.